# Java - Are objects in a list held by value or reference?

Tags: java, list, reference

Simple question, does a list in Java hold objects by value or reference? If I place an object in a list and later on change one of its values, is the one in the list going to have the updated value?

Comment: An object is itself. There is *never* an implicit copy/clone/duplicate on assignment or when passing to a method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does a list in Java hold objects by value or reference?

The *List* is an ordered collection that contains object references.

> If I place an object in a list and later on change one of its values, is the one in the list going to have the updated value?

You can change/update only *mutable* objects. You cannot update *immutable* (e.g `List<String>`) objects via their references.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are stored by reference. If you want to retrieve the value, clone the object by implementing the Cloneable interface and implement your own clone method.

Answer (score 1):

All objects are help by reference in java. A list is held by reference. The objects in it are held by reference. Hence, if you change the values later on it will show the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, by reference, as is the custom with any Java object, unless you intentionally clone the object, and put the copy inside the list.

Comment: And then it's a reference to the copy.

Comment: Of course. And if you change *that* item, you will still be changing the contents of the list. But cloning and passing is usually done to leave a copy behind without change.

Comment: My point was that saying "a copy is put inside the list" blurs the distinction between values and references which is what the OP is trying to figure out, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

User defined data types are always passed by reference, if in your code you defined a list with variables of some classes they are stored by reference