# List referencing to Last object Java

Tags: java

While adding objects to list it is referencing to the last object only.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   obj.setNumber(i+1);
   myList.add(obj);
}
```

When I try printing the myList contents It is printing object with getNumber returning 3 i.e. last object added to list.

But when I try:

```
 MyClass obj;
 List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   obj = new MyClass();
   obj.setNumber(i+1);
   myList.add(obj);
 }
```

It is working fine.I am not able to clearly understand the difference as after forming an Object I have added it to List , why should the contents of List be changing if I am updating Object?

Edit:
I understood the difference in above code snippets.But I have one more doubt:

```
 Map<int,MyClass> myMap = new HashMap<>();
 for(MyClass obj : myList){
     myMap.put(obj.getNumber(),obj);
 }
```

In this case should myMap be able to get all objects?

Comment: In your first example, you are only creating one instance of `MyClass` (`obj`) and are simply adding it to the list 3 times.

Comment: In first example all the list index references are pointing to same object , so no matter which index you call you will get same object. where as in second example every list index is pointing to a different object with different state (i.e number)

Comment: Got it.One more similar doubt.

Comment: I'll update the question.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you please help me understand Edited Code snippet of maps as well.Can we add all objects of myList to myMap in this way?

Comment: You'll still have the same problem as the reference (to the place in memory) is the same for each element in the `Map`.  If you use a `Set`, you "should" find that you can only one add a single instance

Comment: How should I solve this then?

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you have one apple that you put in your bag three times (taking a bite of it every time you put it in). In the end, that apple will be bitten three times -- with every bite covering up the previous one.
Your bag will *appear* to have three apples in it, but if you try to take out apple1, apple2 or apple3, you will actually get the same single apple.

In the second example, you have three apples. You take a (bigger and bigger) bite of each and put it in your bag, ending up with three different apples.

In your last code snippet, the result depends on what is in your list. Since you cannot have duplicate keys in a map, if you have objects with the same `number` value in your list (be it the same instance or not), only one of them (the last in your list) will end up in the map.

For the list built with the first code snippet, your map will be `3 -> obj1`, for the one built with the second snippet, it will be `1 -> obj1, 2 -> obj2, 3 -> obj3`, thus containing all the elements in the list.

If your list would contain two instances with a number value of `2`, only the last instance will be mapped for that key.

Answer (score 0):

In first code snippet you are adding reference of `Myclass` 'obj' and update number by calling `setNumber(i)` first it will add 1 then 2 and 3 on same reference.

while in second snippet you are adding new class and then `setNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the List is a collection which holds references of objects not objects. References are to some extant like pointers in C.
You can also visit this page
[Java - Are objects in a list held by value or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875364/java-are-objects-in-a-list-held-by-value-or-reference)

In the first code you have created one and only one instance of MyClass, then you add its reference to your list for three times.
Therefore all elements of your list are references of one instance, 
and by setting a value to each element in the list, in fact you change the state of that object. 
Something like this
    myList(0) -> obj
    myList(1) -> obj
    myList(2) -> obj

If you fill your map, it will be like this 
    myMap[3, obj]
Because a map cannot contain duplicate keys.

But in the second sample, you have created three instance of MyClass and have added all of them to the list.
And each instance has its own state (number in this case). So by setting a new number to a instance, you don't change other instances state.
Something like this
    myList(0) -> obj1
    myList(1) -> obj2
    myList(2) -> obj3

If you fill your map, it will be like this 
    myMap[1, obj1]
    myMap[2, obj2]
    myMap[3, obj3]